# Why does C not recognize strings across multiple lines?

Tags: c, string, syntax, multiline, multilinestring

(I am very new to C.)

Visual newlines seem to be unimportant in C.
For instance:

```
int i; int j;
```

is same as

```
int i;
int j;
```

and

```
int k = 0 ;
```

is same as

```
int
k
=
0
;
```

so why is

```
"hello
hello"
```

not the same as

```
"hello hello"
```

Comment: Because the stuff that is happens inside the string is not a C code. You could ask the same about breaking a numerical constant like `25` into `2` and `5` on separate lines. More formally, a string literal is a single preprocessing token.

Comment: Intuitively - a string might contain any number of whitespaces after the first "hello" which are not visible in many editors/viewers/print-outs. But a different number of spaces will make up a different string, which will still look the same if written this way. Not a good thing.

Comment: Note however that `"hello"{newline}"hello"` *is* treated the same as `"hello" "hello"`

Comment: @EugeneSh. what you say makes sense, but the example you provided is bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> We can think of a C program as a series of tokens: groups of characters that can't be split up without changing their meaning. Identifiers and keywords are tokens. So are operators like + and -, punctuation marks such as the comma
> and semicolon, and string literals.

For example, the line

```
int i; int j;
```

consists of 6 tokens: **int**, **i**, **;**, **int**, **j** and **;**. Most of the time, and particularly in this case, the amount of space (space, tab and newline characters) is not critical. That's why the compiler will treat

```
int           i
;int
j;
```

The same.

Writing

```
"Hello
 Hello"
```

Is like writing

```
un signed
```

and hope that the compiler treat it as

```
unsigned
```

Just like space is not allowed between a keyword, newline character is not allowed in a string literal token. But it can be included using the newline escape '\n' when needed.

To write strings across lines use string concatenation method

```
"Hello"
"Hello"
```

Although the above method is recommended, you can also use a backslash

```
"Hello \
 Hello"
```

With the backslash method, beware of the beginning space in a new line. The string will include everything in that line until it finds a closing quote or another backslash.

Answer (score 1):

It is because a line that contains a starting quote character and not an ending quote character was more likely a typing mistake or other error than an attempt to write a string across multiple lines, so the decision was made that string literals would not span source lines, unless deliberately indicated with `\` at the end of a line.

Further, when such an error occurs, the compile would be faced with reading possibly thousands of lines of code before determining there was no closing quote character (end of file was reached) or finding what was intended as an opening quote character for some other string literal and then attempting to parse the contents of that string literal as C code. In addition to burdening early compilers with limited compute resources, this could result in confusing error messages in a part of the source code far removed from the missing quote character.

This choice is effected in C 2018 6.4.5 1, which says that a string literal is `"` *s-char-sequence*<sub>opt</sub> `"`, where *s-char-sequence* is any member of the character set except the quote character, a backslash, or a new-line character (and a string literal may also have an encoding prefix, a `u8`, `u`, `U`, or `L` before the first `"`).

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be continued over newlines by putting a backslash immediately before the newline:

```
"hello \
hello"
```

Or (better), using string concatenation:

```
"hello "
"hello"
```

Note that the space has been carefully preserved so that these are equivalent to `"hello hello"` except for the line numbering in the file after the appearance.

The backslash-newline line elimination is done very early in the translation process — in phase 2 of the conceptual [translation phases](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2).

Note that there is no stripping leading blanks or anything.  If you write:

```
printf("Some long string with maybe an integer %d in it\
        and some more data on the next line\n", i);
```

Then the string has a sequence of (at least) 8 blanks in it between `in it` and `and some`.  The count of 8 assumes that the `printf()` statement is aligned in the left margin; if it is indented, you'd need to add the extra white space corresponding to the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

1- using double quotes for each string :

```
char *str = "hello "
"hello" ;
```

** One problem with this approach is that we need to escape specially characters such as quotation mark " itself.

2- Using - \ :

```
char *str = "hello \
hello" ;
```

** This form is a lot easier to write, we don't need to write quotation marks for each line.

Comment: The second option doesn't generate the same string as the first option.  And you need to escape embedded quotes in both variants.  The string concatenation method (option 1) is better; it should be used in modern code (anything written in the current millennium).

Comment: I think it gives the same result and it's just a space problem in the 2nd case that I'm going to fix (any space after - \ will be added to the str string).
The 1st method is less practical since it makes the code less readable.

Comment: On the contrary, using strong concatenation is better, not least because it allows the continuation lines to be indented like the rest of the code.